# WKWebview won't show PDF Annotation

Tags: ios, iphone, pdf, wkwebview

I'm using WKWebView to load PDF files. I've found that all the annotations in the pdf are invisible.

Does anyone know how to fix this bug?

Answer (score 0):

If you open the PDFs in Adobe Acrobat do the annotations display?

In a PDF 1.7 and earlier file, annotations are not required to have their appearance defined in the file and instead PDF viewing applications can generate them when the PDF is opened. Not all PDF viewing applications are capable of generating the appearance of all annotation types though (there are many different annotation types in PDF).

If Acrobat displays the annotations and WKWebview does not, then the annotations are most likely missing their appearances and Acrobat is generating them from what is stored in the PDF.

In PDF 2.0 (recently published as a standard), annotations are required to have a defined normal appearance so that PDF viewers do not have to generate the appearance any longer which will provide a much more consistent experience for those who are reading PDFs (it will be a while before this catches on though).

There are a number of tools out there that can be used to create the appearance for annotations and save them into the PDF so if you determine that the annotations are missing their appearances you can get one of those tools and run the PDFs through it before presenting them in your WKWebview.

Comment: thank you for your answer.After searching online, I didn't find the tools you said. Would you mind kindly recommend one of those tools you mentioned?